# How can I update my panda package in a Spyder Environment?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spyder, updating

I am using pandas 0.17.0 in a Spyder (Python 3.5) Development Environment.
I want to update my pandas' version, but I can't find the information how to do it.

Also, I am worried that the scripts I have written so far, won't work anymore, once I manage to update to a newer pandas version. Is there a way to access various versions of this packages?

I am still very new to this, and maybe I am just looking on the wrong sites. Does anybody know, where I could find some information on this topic?

Comment: If use `win`, use `conda update pandas` in `cmd` and then restart `Spyder`

Comment: [Create another environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) and install the updated version of pandas these so you can still run your scripts with the current version and try the updated one.